# Write text to file in bash script with variable replacement but without backtick replacement

Tags: bash

I'm trying to tidy up my bash script to make use of variables to define repeated things once only.

I'm running into a problem in one part where I am using the bash script to create other bash scripts *for later execution*.

Specifically, I want to avoid backtick execution at the time of running the parent script (so that the backticks are executed only when running the child scripts).  But I also want to make use of variable substitution so that I can make multiple use of a single definition.

What I'm doing at present is along the following lines:

```
GLOBAL="yellow"
BASE="script"
APPS="foo bar"

for APP_NAME in $APPS; do
cat << EOF > ./"$BASE-$APP_NAME"
#!/bin/bash
mkdir ./app--$APP_NAME--$GLOBAL--`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`
# do some other stuff
EOF
chmod +x ./"$BASE-$APP_NAME"
done
```

When I run the above, variable substitution is performed as I want, but the backticked date is expanded at the time of running the parent script.

I know that I can preserve the backticks by using `"EOF"` instead:

```
...
cat << "EOF" > ./"$BASE-$APP_NAME"
...
```

But then variable substitution is not performed!  How do I do this so that variables are substituted *and* backticks are not executed?

I want the generated `script-foo` script to look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir ./app--foo--yellow--`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`
# do some other stuff
```

Comment: Just escape the backticks you don't want to be expanded with a backslash. Also I suggest using the more modern `$(...)` notation instead of backticks, in which case you'd have to escape the $.

Comment: Why are you creating other bash scripts dynamically? That's usually a bad sign. It sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Perhaps you can accomplish the same goal with a single fixed script that takes arguments or a dynamic configuration file.

Comment: @Aaron hmm, yes that's it.  Now I feel stupid.  Thanks.

Comment: @JohnKugelman happy to take advice here... this script is actually a cloud-init script which I'm using to set up various things with a new cloud server, one of which is creating a number of helper scripts which I can execute once the server has spun up.  But yes, it could be a fixed script in this case taking an argument, but sometimes I like seeing all the choices available (and so I can autocomplete using tab) which isn't possible with a single fixed script.

Comment: @JohnKugelman also some of the scripts I'm creating are indeed fixed scripts -- no need to take any argument -- just there as helpers for executing complicated or difficult-to-remember commands.  Is there a better way to achieve this via a cloud-init script?

Comment: I don't know enough about your situation to make a concrete recommendation. Just mentioning it as food for thought. I've learned to avoid dynamically generated scripts. For example, the systems I administer use systemd--all of the scripts I write are fixed, and and dynamic information is stored in the `.service` configuration files, which I do sometimes generate on the fly.